# Problem for open DiffMerge SnailSVN in Mojave

Tags: macos, svn, diffmerge

The first message dialog error is:

> Difftool would like to access “~/Library/Application/Scripts/net.langui.SnailSVN.DiffTool

And after clicking on the button 'Authorize', the second message dialog is:

> Unable to install difftool.sh to the scripts directory!
>   message – “difftool.sh” couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access “net.langui.SnailSVN.DiffTool

Comment: Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on answering your own question.

Answer (score 6):

*Solution by OP.*

To resolve this, I opened a terminal and copied `difftool.sh` manually.

Lite version of SnailSVN:

```
cp /Applications/SnailSVNLite.app/Contents/Applications/DiffTool.app/Contents/Resources/difftool.sh ~/Library/Application\ Scripts/net.langui.SnailSVN.DiffTool/
```

Commercial version of SnailSVN:

```
cp /Applications/SnailSVN.app/Contents/Applications/DiffTool.app/Contents/Resources/difftool.sh ~/Library/Application\ Scripts/net.langui.SnailSVN.DiffTool/
```